# I can't convert int to string in Vaadin

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

I have a small problem with Vaadin and Spring Boot. When I want to change convert int to string I get this error. I know it's probably a trivial problem but I'm just starting to learn Spring Boot.

> com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.IntegerField@1c7a3814

```
@Route("main")
public class vaadinapp extends VerticalLayout {
  public vaadinapp() {
    IntegerField integerField = new IntegerField("Age");
    Button buttonName = new Button("Left", new Icon(VaadinIcon.ACADEMY_CAP));
    Label labelName = new Label();

    String integerFieldStr = integerField.toString();

    buttonName.addClickListener(clickEvent -> {
      labelName.setText(integerFieldStr);
    });

    add(integerField, buttonName, labelName);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to get the value of the field instead of the field itself, like `Integer fieldVal = integerField.getValue();`? You could convert it to `String` afterwards or directly do `fieldVal = integerField.getValue().ToString();`, I think...

Answer (score 2):

Invoking the `toString` method of the `integerField` object will return you string representation of the object, not the value, stored in it. To retrieve the value you could use the `getValue` method instead. Like this:

```
public vaadinapp() {
    IntegerField integerField = new IntegerField("Age");
    Button buttonName = new Button("Left", new Icon(VaadinIcon.ACADEMY_CAP));
    Label labelName = new Label();

    buttonName.addClickListener(clickEvent -> {
        String integerFieldStr = 
            Optional.ofNullable(integerField.getValue()) //you need this check since getValue could return null
           .map(String::valueOf)
           .orElse("");
        labelName.setText(integerFieldStr);
    });

    add(integerField, buttonName, labelName);
}
```

UPD: I'd also moved the value retrieval code into the listener. Thanks Eric for this point.

Comment: And I think OP might want to get the value when clicking the button, which of course requires moving the code inside the click listener.

Comment: Yes, I'd focused on the `toString` issue and missed the one with the listener. Thanks, I've fixed the code